# Bootstrap 4 center-block unable to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following bootstrap html code (its JSX hence the `className` but the idea is the same):

```
<div className="toggleView btn-group center-block" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button onClick={this.handleTimelineClick} type="button" className={this.state.toggleCalendar == false ? "btn btn-secondary active" : "btn btn-secondary"}>Timeline</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleCalendarClick} type="button" className={this.state.toggleCalendar == true ? "btn btn-secondary active " :"btn btn-secondary"}>Calendar</button>
 </div>
```

I am trying to center this code with either bootstrap center-block or with CSS but cannot seem to get it to work:

[image]

The green bar highlights the div `toggleView`.

The only css I am using is the following:

```
.toggleView {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Why can I not center this button group?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`btn-group` has `display:inline-block` so you would use `text-center` in the parent container..

http://codeply.com/go/hyUYkUrtRN

NOTE: In Bootstrap 4, `center-block` is now `mx-auto`, representing `margin: 0 auto;` for centering `display:block` elements. Bootstrap 4 now has a `d-block` class too so an inline element can be made display:block like this..

`<img src=".." class="d-block mx-auto" >`

Also see: [Center the content inside a column in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528411/center-the-content-inside-a-column-in-bootstrap-4/42559095#42559095)

Comment: Thank you, this is a bit confusing to me why this works though. Can you discuss a little more about  `display:inline-block` and what that is actually doing and how text-center solved this problem?

Comment: Basically `center-block` would only work on a `display:block` element

Comment: For future readers it seems like `m-x-auto` is renamed to `mx-auto` fram alpha.5

Comment: What I found in Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6. mx-auto has only two values, margin-left: auto !important and margin-right: auto !important.  vertical-middle class worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap 4 (as of 2017-08-16) will use `d-block` and to center you use `mx-auto`.

Comment: Unless the element has a defined width it does not work at all.

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap 4 does not have `center-block` Instead, I use `d-block mx-auto` which sets display to block, and left and right margins to auto.

Comment: This is now `d-block mx-auto`

Comment: @Kyobul, Are you sure? It has worked for me.  Can you post an example?