# Center the content inside a column in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I Need help to fix the problem, I need to center the content inside the column in bootstrap4, please find my code below

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3">
        <div class="nauk-info-connections">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use can use `class="text-center"`.

Comment: I tried using it but it is not working for Bootstrap4, the text alone is getting centered but I need the div with class "nauk-info-connections" itself to be centered aligned inside the col-3 div.

Comment: I used the traditional method of centering the container

.nauk-info-connections{
 border-radius:50%;
 border:1px solid $nauk-orange;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: class container

Answer (score 259):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Since flexbox is still used the centering methods in Bootstrap 5 work the same way. Columns can be centered using offset, auto-margins or justify-content-center (flexbox).

[Demo of the Bootstrap 5 Centering Methods](https://codeply.com/p/O8BLz8ic1X)

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

There are multiple **horizontal centering methods in Bootstrap 4**...

- `text-center` for center `display:inline` elements
- `offset-*` or `mx-auto` can be used to **center column** (`col-*`)
- or, `justify-content-center` on the `row` to **center columns** (`col-*`)
- `mx-auto` for centering `display:block` elements inside `d-flex`

`mx-auto` (auto x-axis margins) will center `display:block` or `display:flex` elements that have a defined width, (%, vw, px, etc..). Flexbox is used by default on grid columns, so there are also various flexbox centering methods.

[Demo of the Bootstrap 4 Centering Methods](http://www.codeply.com/go/SOSvvKpLOc)

In your case, use `mx-auto` to center the `col-3` and `text-center` to center it's content..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="text-center">
            center
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/GRUfnxl3Ol

***or,*** using `justify-content-center` on flexbox elements (`.row`):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3 text-center">
            center
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also see:
[Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4/42252877#)

Comment: Thanks. What I don't see in any of the examples or Bootstrap docs is horizontal centering of non-inline elements, at different breakpoints. For example, centering a `<select>` at md and above, but left aligning below md.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 4 `select` it's display:block, not display:inline because `form-control` is display:block. Of course the original question wasn't about using responsive breakpoints so that's no explained in the answer.

Answer (score 20):

```js
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
             CenterContent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Enable 'flex' for the column as we want & use justify-content-center

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. phew! thank you ;)

Answer (score 10):

Add class `text-center` to your column:

```
<div class="col text-center">
I am centered
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3 text-center">
            Center text goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used `justify-content-center` class instead of `mx-auto` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559095).

check at https://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazk/4fsp4ywh/

Comment: This is already covered in the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559095)

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett I have used justify-content-center class instead of mx-auto. This is also one method of doing it. People can use this also  I am just trying to help others. Thanks

Comment: Ah, right. Well, a bit of explanation can go a long way.

Answer (score 3):

If your **content** is a **set of buttons** that you want to center on a page, then wrap them in a **row** and use **justify-content-center.**

Sample code below:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">

    <button>Action A</button>
    <button>Action B</button>
    <button>Action C</button> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Really simple answer in **bootstrap 4**, change this

```
<row>
  ...
</row>
```

to this

```
<row class="justify-content-center">
  ...
</row>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.row>.col, .row>[class^=col-] {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```