# Centering text in a table head cell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm having difficult getting the headers of a table to center. The table HTML is below:

```
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table">

  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th><span class="d-none d-md-flex text-center">Disposition</span><span class="d-flex d-md-none mx-auto">Dispo</span></th>
      <th class="text-right">Price</th>
      <th><span class="d-none d-md-flex mx-auto">Match %</span><span class="d-flex d-md-none mx-auto">Match</span></th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id="lisc_recs"></tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

It's this particular column that is giving me heartburn:

```
<th><span class="d-none d-md-flex text-center">Disposition</span><span class="d-flex d-md-none mx-auto">Dispo</span></th>
```

I can get it to center normally using .text-center if there is no responsive display elements inside the , like:

```
<th class="text-center">Disposition</th>
```

Is there a way to center text inside the span when displayed using d-*-flex or d-*-table-cell?

The problem appears to be that the span is always generating itself at full width of the :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Centering content in flexbox elements requires either `justify-content` or `align-items`, not `text-align`.

Use Bootstrap's `justify-content-center` class.

[More on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559095/1264804)